# How can I have multiple people editing the same SQL Server Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me and some friends are working on a school project, and I've been looking for a way to allow us all to work and edit on the same database just like we would on a VS project through GitHub.

I've tried importing the database into an SQL Database project on VS so we could work through GitHub, but I'm not sure if VS is as effective as the actual SSMS.

It doesn't matter if it's not through GitHub, I just want to know if there is a way for us to work on a database without having to export it and then import it again.

Edit: By 'editing' I meant just working on the database overall, make changes, get data, edit tables, etc.

Comment: Set up a SQL Server project and "publish" it when you make changes - it can be in source control the same as other code then; it IS code.

Comment: _"but I'm not sure if VS is as effective as the actual SSMS."_ - they're different tools for doing different things. SSMS is for database _administration_, SSDT (i.e. VS) is for database _design_. And **yes**, SSDT projects (`*.sqlproj`) works fine with source-control, including git (just don't use any of the Designers, they've all gotten worse over time and don't support any of the modern SQL Server features like Temporal/Ledger Tables, Graph Tables, Polybase, etc).

Comment: _"It doesn't matter if it's not through GitHub, I just want to know if there is a way for us to work on a database without having to export it and then import it again."_ - when you say "editing a database" do you mean the database **design** (sans data), or **the data** contained within the database?  or both?

Comment: Schema and data are 2 very different beasts when it comes to database design. Scheme and static-ish data is easy as explained. Data is a totally different ballgame, but shouldn't normally need to be synced.

Comment: @DaleK Tried **Dolt**? It's like git... [but for data](https://docs.dolthub.com/introduction/what-is-dolt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> By 'editing' I meant just working on the database overall, make changes, get data, edit tables, etc.

The short answer is **no**: as of Feburary 2023 there is no established tooling (outside of experimental databases like [Dolt](https://docs.dolthub.com/introduction/what-is-dolt)) for distributed collaborative work on both design-and-data on an RDBMS, especially not in the SQL Server-based Microsoft/VS ecosystem.

The reason why is rooted in a reality of database-centric software development: the actual data within a database is irrelevant to working on the system that consumes and manipulates it (with exceptions[1]), this principle is what enables companies handling very sensitive data (such as medical records, etc) to get any work done: the devs work with fake, generated data that only resembles real-world data, while the *real* data about *real people* lives in a separate database *that almost no-one can access* but it will have the exact same design/schema as the developer's database with the fake data in.

If you want to collaborate *on data and the design* then the "best" approach with today's tooling <sub>in my opinion</sub> is to have a single RDBMS database *in the cloud*[2] like Azure SQL or Amazon RDS - but you should still have your database design/schema in source-control in an SSDT `*.sqlproj` project - and to not directly make design/schema changes to this database without going through SSDT - and only make *data changes* in this live/cloud database.

If you have collaborators that won't always be able to connect to this central single cloud-hosted database then you have *a very hard problem* to solve which is worthy of another question entirely (welcome to [the CAP Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)).

[1]: Exceptions like setup/config/"system" data, and seed data for bootstrapping, or data used in test-cases. Point is: designing a database for animal taxonomy doesn't require *actual* Latin animal species names, and designing a patient/medical database doesn't require having the real details of real people with real conditions stored in your git repository.

[2]: ugh, I hate that word

Comment: Thanks, I've spent almost two whole days trying to look for a way to do it with no success. At least I'm glad to finally know there is no way to do exactly that. Maybe I'll be sticking to a simple commit of the tables to GIthub as a backup.